# Cocos2d Firebase Admob crashes

Tags: android, c++, firebase, admob, cocos2d-x

I’ve installed Firebase, did the whole setup, but when I load my app on my android is says “Unfortunately, (APP) has stopped”. The app is nothing but the default Cocos HelloWorldScene. I'm using cocos2dx 3.15.1, Visual Studio 2013, Android NDK r10e, and SDK Version 26.0.1.

proj.android-studio\app\jni\Android.mk:

```
FIREBASE_CPP_SDK_DIR := ../../../firebase_cpp_sdk

APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a x86
STL := $(firstword $(subst _, ,$(APP_STL)))
FIREBASE_LIBRARY_PATH := $(FIREBASE_CPP_SDK_DIR)/libs/android/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/$(STL)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := firebase_app
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FIREBASE_LIBRARY_PATH)/libapp.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(FIREBASE_CPP_SDK_DIR)/include
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := firebase_feature
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FIREBASE_LIBRARY_PATH)/libadmob.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(FIREBASE_CPP_SDK_DIR)/include
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../cocos2d)
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../cocos2d/external)
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../cocos2d/cocos)
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../cocos2d/cocos/audio/include)

LOCAL_MODULE := MyGame_shared

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libMyGame

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
                   ../../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
                   ../../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp \
                   ../../../Classes/FirebaseHelper.cpp


LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../Classes

# _COCOS_HEADER_ANDROID_BEGIN
# _COCOS_HEADER_ANDROID_END


LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += firebase_app
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += firebase_feature

# _COCOS_LIB_ANDROID_BEGIN
# _COCOS_LIB_ANDROID_END

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,.)

# _COCOS_LIB_IMPORT_ANDROID_BEGIN
# _COCOS_LIB_IMPORT_ANDROID_END
```

AppDelegate.cpp:

```
#include "AppDelegate.h"
#include "HelloWorldScene.h"
#include "firebase/app.h"
#include "firebase/admob.h"

// #define USE_AUDIO_ENGINE 1
// #define USE_SIMPLE_AUDIO_ENGINE 1

#if USE_AUDIO_ENGINE && USE_SIMPLE_AUDIO_ENGINE
#error "Don't use AudioEngine and SimpleAudioEngine at the same time. Please just select one in your game!"
#endif

#if USE_AUDIO_ENGINE
#include "audio/include/AudioEngine.h"
using namespace cocos2d::experimental;
#elif USE_SIMPLE_AUDIO_ENGINE
#include "audio/include/SimpleAudioEngine.h"
using namespace CocosDenshion;
#endif

USING_NS_CC;

static cocos2d::Size designResolutionSize = cocos2d::Size(480, 320);
static cocos2d::Size smallResolutionSize = cocos2d::Size(480, 320);
static cocos2d::Size mediumResolutionSize = cocos2d::Size(1024, 768);
static cocos2d::Size largeResolutionSize = cocos2d::Size(2048, 1536);

AppDelegate::AppDelegate()
{
}

AppDelegate::~AppDelegate() 
{
#if USE_AUDIO_ENGINE
    AudioEngine::end();
#elif USE_SIMPLE_AUDIO_ENGINE
    SimpleAudioEngine::end();
#endif
}

// if you want a different context, modify the value of glContextAttrs
// it will affect all platforms
void AppDelegate::initGLContextAttrs()
{
    // set OpenGL context attributes: red,green,blue,alpha,depth,stencil
    GLContextAttrs glContextAttrs = {8, 8, 8, 8, 24, 8};

    GLView::setGLContextAttrs(glContextAttrs);
}

// if you want to use the package manager to install more packages,  
// don't modify or remove this function
static int register_all_packages()
{
    return 0; //flag for packages manager
}

bool AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
    // initialize director
    auto director = Director::getInstance();
    auto glview = director->getOpenGLView();
    if(!glview) {
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_WIN32) || (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_MAC) || (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_LINUX)
        glview = GLViewImpl::createWithRect("Shaokang", cocos2d::Rect(0, 0, designResolutionSize.width, designResolutionSize.height));
#else
        glview = GLViewImpl::create("Shaokang");
#endif
        director->setOpenGLView(glview);
    }

#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID)
    // Initialize Firebase for Android.
    firebase::App* app = firebase::App::Create(
        firebase::AppOptions(), JniHelper::getEnv(), JniHelper::getActivity());
    // Initialize AdMob.
    firebase::admob::Initialize(*app, "INSERT_YOUR_ADMOB_ANDROID_APP_ID");
#elif (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_IOS)
    // Initialize Firebase for iOS.
    firebase::App* app = firebase::App::Create(firebase::AppOptions());
    // Initialize AdMob.
    firebase::admob::Initialize(*app, "INSERT_YOUR_ADMOB_IOS_APP_ID");
#endif
    // Initialize AdMob.
    firebase::admob::Initialize(*app);

    // turn on display FPS
    director->setDisplayStats(true);

    // set FPS. the default value is 1.0/60 if you don't call this
    director->setAnimationInterval(1.0f / 60);

    // Set the design resolution
    glview->setDesignResolutionSize(designResolutionSize.width, designResolutionSize.height, ResolutionPolicy::NO_BORDER);
    auto frameSize = glview->getFrameSize();
    // if the frame's height is larger than the height of medium size.
    if (frameSize.height > mediumResolutionSize.height)
    {        
        director->setContentScaleFactor(MIN(largeResolutionSize.height/designResolutionSize.height, largeResolutionSize.width/designResolutionSize.width));
    }
    // if the frame's height is larger than the height of small size.
    else if (frameSize.height > smallResolutionSize.height)
    {        
        director->setContentScaleFactor(MIN(mediumResolutionSize.height/designResolutionSize.height, mediumResolutionSize.width/designResolutionSize.width));
    }
    // if the frame's height is smaller than the height of medium size.
    else
    {        
        director->setContentScaleFactor(MIN(smallResolutionSize.height/designResolutionSize.height, smallResolutionSize.width/designResolutionSize.width));
    }

    register_all_packages();

    // create a scene. it's an autorelease object
    auto scene = HelloWorld::createScene();

    // run
    director->runWithScene(scene);

    return true;
}

// This function will be called when the app is inactive. Note, when receiving a phone call it is invoked.
void AppDelegate::applicationDidEnterBackground() {
    Director::getInstance()->stopAnimation();

#if USE_AUDIO_ENGINE
    AudioEngine::pauseAll();
#elif USE_SIMPLE_AUDIO_ENGINE
    SimpleAudioEngine::getInstance()->pauseBackgroundMusic();
    SimpleAudioEngine::getInstance()->pauseAllEffects();
#endif
}

// this function will be called when the app is active again
void AppDelegate::applicationWillEnterForeground() {
    Director::getInstance()->startAnimation();

#if USE_AUDIO_ENGINE
    AudioEngine::resumeAll();
#elif USE_SIMPLE_AUDIO_ENGINE
    SimpleAudioEngine::getInstance()->resumeBackgroundMusic();
    SimpleAudioEngine::getInstance()->resumeAllEffects();
#endif
}
```

HelloWorldScene.cpp:

```
#include "HelloWorldScene.h"
#include "SimpleAudioEngine.h"
#include "FirebaseHelper.h"
#include "firebase/admob.h"
#include "firebase/admob/types.h"
#include "firebase/app.h"
#include "firebase/future.h"
#include "firebase/admob/banner_view.h"

USING_NS_CC;

firebase::admob::BannerView* banner_view;

Scene* HelloWorld::createScene()
{
    return HelloWorld::create();
}

// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
bool HelloWorld::init()
{
    //////////////////////////////
    // 1. super init first
    if ( !Scene::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }

    auto visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
    Vec2 origin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();

    /////////////////////////////
    // 2. add a menu item with "X" image, which is clicked to quit the program
    //    you may modify it.

    // add a "close" icon to exit the progress. it's an autorelease object
    auto closeItem = MenuItemImage::create(
                                           "CloseNormal.png",
                                           "CloseSelected.png",
                                           CC_CALLBACK_1(HelloWorld::menuCloseCallback, this));

    closeItem->setPosition(Vec2(origin.x + visibleSize.width - closeItem->getContentSize().width/2 ,
                                origin.y + closeItem->getContentSize().height/2));

    // create menu, it's an autorelease object
    auto menu = Menu::create(closeItem, NULL);
    menu->setPosition(Vec2::ZERO);
    this->addChild(menu, 1);

    /////////////////////////////
    // 3. add your codes below...

    // add a label shows "Hello World"
    // create and initialize a label

    auto label = Label::createWithTTF("Hello World", "fonts/Marker Felt.ttf", 24);

    // position the label on the center of the screen
    label->setPosition(Vec2(origin.x + visibleSize.width/2,
                            origin.y + visibleSize.height - label->getContentSize().height));

    // add the label as a child to this layer
    this->addChild(label, 1);

    // add "HelloWorld" splash screen"
    auto sprite = Sprite::create("HelloWorld.png");

    // position the sprite on the center of the screen
    sprite->setPosition(Vec2(visibleSize.width/2 + origin.x, visibleSize.height/2 + origin.y));

    // add the sprite as a child to this layer
    this->addChild(sprite, 0);


#if defined(__ANDROID__)
    // Android ad unit IDs.
    const char* kBannerAdUnit = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";
#else
    // iOS ad unit IDs.
    const char* kBannerAdUnit = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716";
#endif

    // Create and initialize banner view.
    firebase::admob::BannerView* banner_view;
    banner_view = new firebase::admob::BannerView();
    firebase::admob::AdSize ad_size;
    ad_size.ad_size_type = firebase::admob::kAdSizeStandard;
    ad_size.width = 320;
    ad_size.height = 50;
    banner_view->Initialize(getAdParent(), kBannerAdUnit, ad_size);

    // Schedule updates so that the Cocos2d-x update() method gets called.
    this->scheduleUpdate();

    return true;
}


void HelloWorld::menuCloseCallback(Ref* pSender)
{
    //Close the cocos2d-x game scene and quit the application
    Director::getInstance()->end();

    #if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_IOS)
    exit(0);
#endif

    /*To navigate back to native iOS screen(if present) without quitting the application  ,do not use Director::getInstance()->end() and exit(0) as given above,instead trigger a custom event created in RootViewController.mm as below*/

    //EventCustom customEndEvent("game_scene_close_event");
    //_eventDispatcher->dispatchEvent(&customEndEvent);


}

void HelloWorld::update(float delta) {
    // Check that the banner has been initialized.
    if (banner_view->InitializeLastResult().status() ==
        firebase::kFutureStatusComplete) {
        // Check that the banner hasn't started loading.
        if (banner_view->LoadAdLastResult().status() ==
            firebase::kFutureStatusInvalid) {
            // Make the banner visible and load an ad.
            CCLOG("Loading a banner.");
            banner_view->Show();
            firebase::admob::AdRequest my_ad_request = {};
            banner_view->LoadAd(my_ad_request);
        }
    }
}
```

My app is literally the default project, only with everything from the Firebase tutorial added to it, and it crashes. I have installed the firebase_cpp file, the FirebaseHelper header and source are both exactly how they are when in the tutorial, and everything else in the Cocos2d app, at least I think, is all the default things. What do I do? What could it be?

When I run the app in Android Studio, it says the error: `E/firebase: Unable to check Google Play services availablity as the com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability class is not present in this application.`

Answer (score 0):

I think Google Play Services is not available. you can check it via following method:-

/**
     * used to check if google play service is available or not
     * @param context
     * @return
     */

```
public boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Context context) {
    GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int resultCode = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
    return resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: What code file do I put this in, and what do I do if it is, or is not available?

Comment: Actually I think you need to install play service before doing firebase integration. else you should show some kind of popup to user.
Also you should  run this code on device having installed GPS.